# CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA error occur while unit testing with jasmine and karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am doing unit testing with jasmine and karma. I am able to run test in simple application but when i am testing method of a page that has other component it shows error like this

> If 'custom-component' is a Web Component then add 
>       'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component 
>       to suppress this message

**custom-component.html**

```
<div class="data-container">
    <ion-row>
        <!-- Display week Day and Dates -->
        <ion-col class="no-padding" *ngFor="let days of weekDates">
            <div class="header-circle">
                <!-- Header-Circle for Day -->
                <p class="uppercase thick day-color">{{ days.day }}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="{{days.day_date}}" (click)="toggle(days)" class="{{days.iconClass}}">
                <!-- Circle for Date -->
                <p class="uppercase thick day-color">{{ days.date }}</p>
            </div>
        </ion-col>
        <!-- End of loop -->
    </ion-row>
</div>
```

**custom-component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-component',
    templateUrl: 'custom-component.html'
})
export class custom-component {//Some Code Here }
```

**Checkin.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>{{ spaceName }}</ion-title>
        <!-- added spaceName as title  -->
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="checkin-content" no-bounce>
    <custom-component [inputDate]="selectedDate" (dateChanged)="dateChanged($event)"></custom-component>
</ion-content>
```

**Checkin.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, ModalController, NavParams, NavController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { custom-component } from '../../components/custom-component/custom-component';

export class CheckinPage {

    public isNumberEven(num: number): boolean {
        return num % 2 === 0;
    }

    public isNumberOdd(num: number): boolean {
        return !this.isNumberEven(num);
    }
}
```

**Checkin.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from '../../app/app.component';
import { CheckinPage } from './checkin';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { custom-component } from '../../components/custom-component/custom-component';

let comp: CheckinPage;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<CheckinPage>;
let de: DebugElement;
let el: HTMLElement;
let datepipe: DatePipe;

describe('Checkin Component', () => {

    beforeEach(async(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({

            declarations: [MyApp, CheckinPage, RoatedDateComponent],

            providers: [
                NavController
            ],

            imports: [
                IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
            ]

        }).compileComponents();

    }));

    beforeEach(() => {

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CheckinPage);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;

    });

    afterEach(() => {
        fixture.destroy();
        comp = null;
        de = null;
        el = null;
    });

    it("should correctly classify numbers as odd", () => {
        expect(comp.isNumberOdd(1)).toBe(true);
        expect(comp.isNumberOdd(2)).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

**checkin.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CheckinPage } from './checkin';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CheckinPage,
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(CheckinPage),
    ],
})
export class CheckinPageModule { }
```

Can anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you configure the `TestBed` it is equivalent to creating a new Module. A Module cannot use a Component that has not been added to it. This is the scenario you are running into. The `Checkin` component cannot find a reference to the `custom-component` because it was not declared inside the `TestBed` config. For simple coponents you can always just declare the component inside of the test fixture and everything should work.

The Angular team recommends creating [stub components](https://angular.io/guide/testing#stubbing-unneeded-components) to better test the interactions between the parent and child components.

To create a stub, create a new component that has the same `@Input` and `@Output` fields as the component you are stubbing as well as the same selector. Angular uses the selector to identify the component in the view so as long as the selectors are the same the app will be able to run.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'custom-component',
    template: ' '
})
export class CustomComponentStub {//Some Code Here }
```

And then provide it to the test bed:

```js
declarations: [MyApp, CheckinPage, RoatedDateComponent, CustomComponentStub],
```

I only ever skip creating a stub if the child component is view-only and has no logic. If this is your scenario you can skip adding a stub component by adding the `custom-component` to the declaration list of the `TestBed` like so:

```js
declarations: [MyApp, CheckinPage, RoatedDateComponent, CustomComponent],
```

Comment: Generally a stub shouldn't be recommended to skip, exactly for same reasons why stub components was recommented in the first place. This just prevents the app from being properly tested.

Comment: I added custom-component to declaration part and the above error is solved but as my page also uses service it gives me error like this "Error: No provider for EmployeeService!" and when i add EmployeeService to my Testbed provider it shows 0 tests completed. @TeddySterne

Comment: This is why you should use a stub instead of the actual component. Stubs have no dependencies and allow you to write helper methods to access information about the child component as well as emit data from the child which is then used by the component under test.